# HTTPS requests for GKE Ingress ERR_TIMEDOUT

Tags: kubernetes, https, dns, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a microservice architecture (implemented in Spring Boot) deployed in Google Kubernetes Engine. For this microservice architecture I have setup the following:

- domain: comanddev.tk (free domain from Freenom)
  [image]
- a certificate for this domain
- the following Ingress config:
  [image]

The problem is that when I invoke an URL that I know it should be working https://comanddev.tk/customer-service/actuator/health, the response I get is ERR_TIMEDOUT. I checked Ingress Controller and I don't receive any request in the ingress although URL forwarding is set.

Update: I tried to set a "glue record" like in the following picture and the response I get is that the certificate is not valid (i have certificate for comanddev.tk not dev.comanddev.tk) and I get 401 after agreeing to access unsecure url.
[image]

Comment: Are you using Nginx Ingress or GCP Ingress? What GKE version are you using. What exactly is the error? Could you provide your YAMLs? Did you configure Firewall?

Comment: @PjoterS GCP Ingress, I think. GKE 1.15.12-gke.2. The error is the one already explained. what exactly from YAML and what YAML are you refering to? How to configure Firewall?

Comment: When I `$ curl -IL http://comanddev.tk/customer-service/actuator/health` Im getting response. Also you are using `nginx ingress`. Please provide more details.How did you create certificates, your whole `Ingress` YAML (without personal data). Do you have HTTPS port open? Did you followed [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl) or did you use 3rd party software?

Answer (score 0):

I've digged a bit into this.

As I mentioned when you `$ curl -IL http://comanddev.tk/customer-service/actuator/health` you will received `nginx ingress` response.

As domain intercepts the request and redirect to the destination server I am not sure if there is point to use TLS.

I would suggest you to use `nameserver` instead of `URL Forwarding`, just use `IP` of your `Ingress`. In this option you would redirect request to your Ingress. When you are using `Port Forwarding` you are using [Freenom](https://www.freenom.com/en/index.html?lang=en) `redirection` and I am not sure how its handled on their side.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS and thank you for your interest. I still don't have a solution. I've updated with  what happens after I try your way. Still doesn't work, I get 401

Comment: The good part is that I see requests coming into the loadbalancer, I see the logs. But I don't understand why I get 401

Comment: URL that I am trying to hit is: https://dev.comanddev.tk/customer-service/actuator/health
This is unrestricted and should provide valid response

Comment: Set debug log level in one of the microservices and the /actuator/health arrives and returns 200 OK but Ingress returns 401. I don't know how to check why it returns 401